# Python: Using .isalpha() to count specific words/characters in a word count

Tags: python, count, word-count, isalpha

I've created a function which can count specific words or characters in a text file.

But I want to create a condition where the function only counts a character if it is surrounded by letters. For example in the text file.

```
'This test is an example, this text doesn't have any meaning. It is only an example.'
```

If I were to run this text through my function, testing for the count of apostrophes ('), it will return 3. However I want it to return 1, only for apostrophes within 2 letter characters (e.g isn't or won't), but I want it to ignore every other apostrophe, such a single quotes, that aren't surrounded in letters.

I've tried to use the .isalpha() method but am having trouble with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions would be better for this, but if you must use `isalpha`, something like:

```
s = "'This test is an example, this text doesn't have any meaning. It is only an example.'"
sum(s[i-1].isalpha() and s[i]=="'" and s[i+1].isalpha() for i in range(1,len(s)-1))
```

returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to discount the quotes that are enclosing the string itself, the easiest way might be just to `strip` those off the string before counting.

```
>>> text = "'This test is an example, this text doesn't have any meaning. It is only an example.'"
>>> text.strip("'").count("'")
1
```

Another way would be with a regular expression like `\w'\w`, i.e. letter, followed by `'`, followed by letter:

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in re.finditer("\w'\w", text))
1
```

This also works for quotes inside the string:

```
>>> text = "Text that has a 'quote' in it."
>>> sum(1 for _ in re.finditer("\w'\w", text))
0
```

But it will also miss apostrophs that are not followed by another letter:

```
>>> text = "All the houses' windows were broken."
>>> sum(1 for _ in re.finditer("\w'\w", text))
0
```

Answer (score 0):

As xnx already noted, the proper way to do this is with regular expressions:

```
import re

text = "'This test is an example, this text doesn't have any meaning. It is only an example.'"

print(len(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z]", text)))
"""
Out:
    1
"""
```

Here the apostrophe in the pattern is surrounded by the set of English letters, but there are a number of predefined character sets, see the [RE docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use regex:

```
import re

text = "'This test is an example, this text doesn't have any meaning. It is only an example.'"

wordWrappedApos = re.compile(r"\w'\w")
found = re.findall(wordWrappedApos, text)
print(found)
print(len(found))
```

Substitute "\w" for "[A-Za-z]" if you want to make sure no numbers are in there.